# What were the divisions of the city of Paris between the 12th and 13th centuries?

Tags: maps

What were the divisions (neighborhoods/districts) of the city of Paris during the medieval period? I know there is a division between left and right bank and Ilé de la cité, but I believe there should be more specific neighborhoods or regions, such as a street of artisans, noble neighborhoods and so on.

Are there any maps showing these divisions?

Comment: Paris was tiny at the time. :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Paris#Historical_population (Rome had a million inhabitants before its collapse.)

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: What part of the medieval period are you interested in?  Bear in mind that '_medieval_' covers a period of about 1,000 years, from the 5th to the 15th century.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: For some reason, Mark edited the title to remove that information. I took the liberty of partially reversing the change.

Comment: Wikipedia has a series of maps [Chronologic old maps of Paris](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Chronologic_old_maps_of_Paris), several of which fall within your period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official administration division names probably didn't exist before 1795.

Based on the **Paris de 1285 a 1314, les pelletiers sont dans la Cité** Map, there were 3 sub-divisions

- **Quartier d'outre Grand Pont** (A, North, Right bank)

  - **La Ville**
- **La Cité** (B, Île de la Cité)
- **Quartier d'outre Petit Pont** (C, South, Left bank)

  - **Université**

So outside the **La Cité**, you had the **Neighborhood at** the big and small bridge.
Later maps show only the names (La Ville, Cité, Université).

The areas **outside** of  the city wall were called [**Faubourg**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faubourg#Paris) (suburb)  togeather with main street name.

[image]

On 11 October 1795, Paris was divided into twelve [arrondissements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrondissements_of_Paris).